Are moral statements closed under negation?
Is the class of moral statements closed under negation? That is, if X is a moral statement, is not-X also a moral statement? I believe moral statements are closed under negation, but I would like to see what philosophers have written about this topic.

In standard deontic logics we hsve negation closure. I suppose you could use a base logic that doesn’t use negation, but I’m not sure how that would look.

Define "moral statement". Denying statements about morality is routine in moral discourse, and formalizations of ethics in deontic logic are typically closed under standard  connectives, including negation. So if "moral statement" is loosely taken to mean a statement related to morality then yes, its negation would still be related to morality.
